# Splunk: Removing all text after a specific string in a column

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a field where all values have the following format:

Knowledge:xyz,id:2907129

The id number always changes, however, all I want is the value of xyz.

I used the following to remove "Knowledge:"e

```
eval url=replace (url, "Open_KnowledgeZone:", "")
```

For the id portion, using ",id*" did not work within the eval replace function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a regex.  Something like:

```
rex field=url "(?<=Knowledge:)(?<AnyFieldName>.*)(?=,)"
```

Where `<AnyFieldName>` is the name you want the result field to be.  This will select all characters after "Knowledge:" and before the ",".

Here is the regex in action outside of Splunk:

https://regex101.com/r/ofW0a1/1

Comment: And this is a very simple example.  You could make it more elegant, such as searching for the first ":" instead of the literal "Knowledge:".  You can make more restrictive, such as making sure "xyz" are always three characters long; right now it will take any string up to the first ",".

If you are unfamiliar with Regular Expressions here is a great place to start:

https://regexone.com/

Comment: That worked great! And thank you for the additional info. I will definitely read up on it!